# Common Qt questions

Tags: qt, qt4

I have learned the basics of Qt and now interested in the depths of that pretty library. Please help me to understand:

1. Are the all classes derived from **QObject**?
2. Why is it possible to paint on a **QWidget** (and derived classes)?
3. What does the line `return app.exec();` mean? What does **exec()** method do?
4. Are there **virtual slots**? And **virtual signals**?

Thanks.

Comment: you cant paint on a plain QWidget as far as i know. You can only paint on objects of a class which derives from QWidget, since you have to override the paintEvent function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. All classes that need Qt's [object model](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/object.html) (e.g. by using signals and slots) must derive from QObject.
2. So that you can implement your own widgets, with a customised look. Any sensible GUI library would let you do that.
3. [As documented](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qapplication.html#exec), it enters the Qt event loop.
4. Slots can be virtual. Since signals do not have implementation (or rather, moc generates their implementation), they cannot be made virtual.

Qt has really good and extensive documentation, if you have more questions then they are probably already answered there. Start with [Programming with Qt](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qt-basic-concepts.html) section.

Comment: Not satisfied at all for points 2 and 4, thanks anyway (for answer and links).

Comment: @Dehumanizer: What more do you expect (for 4, Qt docs specifically say "yes" for virtual slots and "no" for virtual signals; for 2, there isn't much more to be said)?

Comment: I'm interested about the QPaintDevice(what is it?). And have compiled an application with virtual signals(also I understand that virtual signal is out of 'mind') and compilation has finished successfully. So I'm interested in details. Thanks.

Comment: @Dehumanizer: You can add 'virtual' keyword to the signal, but that doesn't make much sense (as you can't override its implementation anywhere anyway). Painting system is documented here: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/paintsystem.html

Comment: @CatPlusPlus How did that link happen?